# Laravel eloquent from DB

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a very complicated db query, but I would like to know or is a possibility to short it and make it easier by eloquent?
My Model and his db is :

```
class Order extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;
public $incrementing = false;

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProducts::class);
}

public function statuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderStatusNames::class, 'order_statuses', 'order_id', 'status_id');
}

public function actualKioskOrders()
{
 return 
    $rows = DB::select("SELECT o.id, o.number, o.name client_name, o.phone, 
     o.email, o.created_at order_date,  osn.name actual_status 
     FROM orders o 
     JOIN order_statuses os ON os.order_id = o.id 
     JOIN (SELECT o.id id, MAX(os.created_at) last_status_date FROM orders o 
     JOIN order_statuses os ON os.order_id = o.id GROUP BY o.id) t 
     ON t.id = os.order_id AND t.last_status_date = os.created_at 
     JOIN order_status_names osn ON osn.id = os.status_id
     WHERE os.status_id != 3");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Laravel query builder implements everything you need.

See [Laravel Docs: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries), it have [join methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins), [where clause methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses) and [select methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects).

You can do for example the following:

```
Order::select(['id','number', 'name', 'client_name'])
->where('status_id', '!=', 3)
->join('order_statuses', 'order_statuses.order_id, '=', 'orders.id')
->get()
```

That's just an example on how you can create queries. Chain many methods that you need to create your query, the docs show many ways to do it, including with more complex joins if you need.

Comment: Wow, but this select is only for ORders in this case? Because I need data also from other columns from another joined table. Can I ass this in select?

Comment: Yes you can, just do as you would do on a sql query, prefix with the table name. This will return an collection of you model filled with the selected columns.

Comment: ohh it so difficut to change my query to eloquent!